# How can I get an enchanted item that cannot be used in a grindstone?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I'm trying to create a joke item (a book with quick charge 32k). This item should be completely useless.

I know a way of making the book "too expensive" to apply in an anvil in survival mode, but I do not want players to use it in a grindstone, which would yield 200+ levels.

Is there a way of using the `/give` command which either makes it unusable in a grindstone, gives no XP, etc?

I'm on Minecraft Java edition version 1.16.5.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to give yourself an enchanting book that looks like a real level 32k Quick Charge book by changing the lore and name, like so:

```
/give @s enchanted_book{display:{Name:'[{"text":"Enchanted Book","italic":"false","color":"yellow"}]',Lore:['[{"text":"Quick Charge enchantment.level.32767","italic":"false","color":"gray"}]']}} 1
```

Comment: Does the enchanted book in your example give any xp?

Comment: Nope, it's just a book.

Answer (score 2):

You could code the game so that whenever somebody uses a grindstone, they lose however much XP as the Grindstone would give the user (Maybe by using the XP command on Grindstone used?).

Comment: lol nice idea m8. XD

Answer (score 0):

Grindstones did not exist before 1.14, so if you aren't tied to the current game version, you could use 1.13 instead of 1.14.